# Deselecting/clear selected text for copy process on long click

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

```
**UPDATE**
```

After implement on my way I am able to cancel text control but in gingerbread version upto.
In this jelly been no keycode combination was worked I have tried with this example also but no more luck for new version to manually dispatch keyevent.

I have webview in viewpager now user can copy text from webview on long click on webview, but the problem is when user long click on webview and cursor are shown on view for selected text area and they move right/left then viewpager also move. To over come this I have disable viewpager paging change event on long click and it works.

Now to enable this and clear/deselecting high lighten text on webview to cancel copy text process I didn't find any solution.

check Image here

[image]

**Edited**

Does anybody knows how to programmatically cancel this process like we click on right/done button?

here is the code start selection on text on long click of webview

```
public void SelectText(View v) {
    try {
        KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, 0, 0);
        shiftPressEvent.dispatch(v);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

now how to cancel/dismiss this selection and clear lightening text as programmatically.

I have tried same code with ACTION_UP with above code but no luck
does anybody tried know about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cancel

I have do this

```
public void SelectText(View v) {
    try {
        KeyEvent shiftPressEvent = new KeyEvent(0, 0, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ESCAPE, 0, 0);
        shiftPressEvent.dispatch(v);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

and this worked for gingerbread version but not working in 4.0 version I don't know why this not working but try to find way also

Thank you